# How do I address a formal letter to a married couple who are both pastors

Tags: letter

I'm not sure if I should address them individually or as a pair

Sehr geehrter Herr und Frau Schmidt
or
Sehr geehrte Pfarrer Schmidt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way to do this is

```
Sehr geehrte Frau Schmidt,
sehr geehrter Herr Schmidt,
```

If you don't want to specifically adress them in their capacity as pastors, I would leave the "Pfarrer" out.

Comment: In the past it was common to use "Hochwürden" when adressing a pastor, but today this is obsolete, much like using "Fräulein" when addressing an unmarried woman.

Comment: I had capitalized the second *sehr* also. Looks much better.

Comment: I agree that it looks better but it seems to be very uncommon to capitalize the second "sehr".

Comment: Sometimes one has to be brave …

Comment: It's not very uncommon to capitalize the second "sehr", it's simply wrong. Nevertheless your answer is todays standard of adressing two people. One may only choose to write it in 1 or 2 lines.

Comment: Great advice. I decided to include the pastor title...Sehr geehrte Frau Pfarrerin Schmidt...sehr geehrter Herr Pfarrer Schmidt